# Google analytics dimenson values are random guids

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting a custom dimension in GA with right index

window.ga('set', dimension5, value);

The value I am setting is `true`, `false` & `error`.

But when looking at the Google analytics dashboard I am getting some other values as well which are random guids, like:

```
(19dc2e4a-50cb-42ad-bb37-aa3129a72bcf,636229408930000000)
```

I am not setting those values but how am I getting those?

Here is the code snippet.

Hi Tony, thank you for getting back. I have done GA dimensions in past and have never experienced this problem. Dimension5 is a brand new dimension we have created and it has never been used in past.

My code looks like this.

```
variantAssignment.getVariant(contextId, success, failure);

function success(){
    if(response.data.variantName === 'WithTrue')
        sendGaEvent("true");
    }else{
    sendGaEvent("false");
   }
}

function error(){
  sendGaEvent("error");
}

 function sendGaEvent(value) {
   googleAnalyticsService.setDimension("dimension5", value);
 }

The code in GoogleAnalyticsService looks like this.

function setDimension(dimension, value) {
   if (window.ga !== undefined) {
      window.ga('set', dimension, value);
     }
  }
```

And in the dashboard, my report looks like this.

```
**EnquiryReassuranceMVT**                                  **Users** 
false                                                       20,181  
true                                                        1,307  
058332c5-67e2-48b8-96e5-a7bf08aff7cc,636168368830000000     1
0f6fa9a1-ab32-497e-b817-02dbf4c70e26,636232937030000000     1
23dc5dec-aa78-4d4c-a53f-eaf4240b1123,636225308770000000     1
32f7ca5d-9158-4aec-8a9e-ca94f62bbc2c,636226820520000000     1
488866af-4301-4bb6-b055-804bbc3b6c83,636233922490000000     1
6140a30f-0aa0-4d85-992d-255006fc5a8b,636233678080000000     1
```

Comment: Raj, any chance you might be setting the dimension value for the same dimension slot (5) on different page? What's the scope of the dimension?

Comment: No, this is a new dimension. And also the last page of our journey.

Comment: what's the scope of the dimension? Could you add Page as a secondary dimension to validate that it's really being set on the last page of the journey?

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to answer you question without knowing your level of knowledge and experience with GA.

If you are not very experienced with it you may need to confirm report dates. Sometimes old values may be present in custom dimension, so you may see them.

If it is not the case, it will be helpful to see screenshots of all settings/code pieces and reports you are looking at, as with the information you provided helping you is more of a guessing game.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for getting back. I have updated the question with my code snippet.

Comment: Hi Raj

So, from your report it looks like most of the values are correct and just a few are wrong.

It really looks like you are using same dimension on some other pages (or it is old data). Try to see during which period these "wrong" values appeared and on which pages they are being set.